# How to set Terraform output_path based on source checksum?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

A typical issue with lambda, is that Terraform doesn't seem to realise the zipped payload is updated unless the file name changes.

- [Terraform does not update AWS canary code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069491/terraform-does-not-update-aws-canary-code)
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18089#issuecomment-1007767809

Say I have code that looks like:

```
data "archive_file" "canary_archive_file" {
  for_each = var.endpoints
  type     = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/tmp/${each.key}.zip"

  source {
    content = templatefile("${path.module}/canary-lambda.js.tpl", {
      endpoint = each.value.url
    })
    filename = "nodejs/node_modules/index.js"
  }
}
```

It's not apparent how to set the output_path based on the checksum (md5?) of the source content. Subsequently I need to use that path in the [zip_file parameter for aws_synthetics_canary](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/synthetics_canary#zip_file).

Comment: You can't set `output_path` based on checksum. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: So that aws_synthetics_canary knows the zip_file has been updated and needs to be uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using `md5` function:

```
locals {
  file_content = { for k, v in var.endpoints:
     k => templatefile("${path.module}/canary-lambda.js.tpl", {
      endpoint = v.url
    })
  }
}

data "archive_file" "canary_archive_file" {
  for_each = var.endpoints
  type     = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/tmp/${each.key}-${md5(local.file_content[each.key])}.zip"

  source {
    content = local.file_content[each.key]
    filename = "nodejs/node_modules/index.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up putting this code upon https://github.com/kaihendry/terraform-aws-canary/blob/main/main.tf